# how to create an empty 2 dimensional list based on another 2 dimensional list's length value?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a 2 dimensional empty list, please see code:

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9],[1],[]]
empty_2dimen_list = [[],[],[],[],[]]
ctr = 0
for row in my_list:
    empty_2dimen_list[ctr]=' '.join([str(elem) for elem in row])
    ctr+=1
print(empty_2dimen_list)
```

output is `['1 2 3 4', '5 6', '7 8 9', '1', '']` which is ok .. ,
but I do not know how to make 2 dimensional empty list from list empty_2dimen_list with the same length as my_list without typing multiple brackets inside a bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def createList(l: list):
    new_l = [[] for i in l]
    return new_l

my_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9],[1],[]]
empty_2dimen_list = createList(my_list)
print(empty_2dimen_list)
>>>  [[], [], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use append instead of creating empty lists of lists:

```
empty_2dimen_list = []
for row in my_list:
    empty_2dimen_list.append(' '.join([str(elem) for elem in row]))
```

or even list comprehension:

```
empty_2dimen_list = [' '.join([str(elem) for elem in row]) for row in my_list]
```

output:

```
['1 2 3 4', '5 6', '7 8 9', '1', '']
```